# $(document).ready() works but $.ready() does not

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    $(document).on('click', 'a[data-iframe-menu-entry="data-iframe-menu-entry"]', function(event) {
        alert('hola');
....
```

vs

```
$.ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click', 'a[data-iframe-menu-entry="data-iframe-menu-entry"]', function(event) {
        alert('hola');
....
```

`$.ready()` is supposed to be an alias, but it does not work for me. What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct form of alias is:

```
$(function() {
   // Your code 
});
```